# Using mailmerge with scrlttr2 KOMA letter class

Tags: letters, scrlttr2

I'm trying to use the `mailmerge` package with the KOMA `scrlttr2` letter class, but it is failing with a `There's no line here to end.` message, presumably because the address field is rendering as blank. I expect I am making some elementary mistake. Sample code follows:

```
\documentclass[foldmarks=false,backaddress=false,
fromalign=false,version=last]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mailmerge}
\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{H. G. Wells}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Spade House\\ 5281 Radnor Cliff Crescent (West Side)\\ Sandgate, Kent}
\mailfields{address}
\def\today{1st January, 1895}
\begin{letter}{
    % George Bernard Shaw,\\
    % Shaw's Corner,\\
    % Bibbs Hall Lane,\\
    % Ayot St. Lawrence, Hertfordshire\\
    \mailrepeat{\field{address}}
  }

\opening{Dear Shaw,}

You suck!

\closing{Sincerely}
\end{letter}

\mailentry{GBS}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you bound to the `mailmerge` package? If not, you may want to try the `datatool`package instead. Please see this sample code  (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203918/latex-document-containing-csv-data-with-empty-fields/204111#204111) from Nicola Talbot. It works like a charm with `scrlttr2`.

Comment: @blue_tiger300 I use datatool, yes. But mailmerge seems nice and simple, and ideally customized for this purpose. `datatool`, dunno. Not so much.

Comment: @FaheemMitha  also `textmerg` is  nice and simple. Please see  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89803/11604

Comment: @Fran thanks for the tip. Do you have any thoughts on the differences between `mailmerge` and `textmerg`?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Sorry, beside that I used one or two times `textmerg` but never `mailmerge`, I have  not comparative thoughts  about these packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using `\mailrepeat` correctly. Its argument should be the text that you want to repeat, which is not the address but the whole letter:

```
\documentclass[foldmarks=false,backaddress=false,
fromalign=false,version=last]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mailmerge}
\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{H. G. Wells}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Spade House\\ 5281 Radnor Cliff Crescent (West Side)\\ Sandgate, Kent}
\mailfields{address}
\def\today{1st January, 1895}

\mailrepeat{
  \begin{letter}{
    % George Bernard Shaw,\\
    % Shaw's Corner,\\
    % Bibbs Hall Lane,\\
    % Ayot St. Lawrence, Hertfordshire\\
    \field{address}
  }

  \opening{Dear Shaw,}

  You suck!

  \closing{Sincerely}
  \end{letter}}

\mailentry{GBS}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, Ulrike. Indeed, it was a foolish mistake, as  I thought.